# Attributes undefined when accessing via JQuery livequery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm very new to JQuery so this will probably sound ridiculous but I have a form that repopulates data via AJAX into a div section.  The problem I'm having is that I have a link where I need to access some table row attributes that get rendered to the page during the AJAX refresh but the attributes are all undefined according to my alerts I set up.  Does anyone know how I can access that data again in livequery?  Below is the code.

```
//Rebind anchor tags for add links.
$('a[class=add_player]') 
    .livequery('click', function(event) { 

    var parentRow = $(this).parent().parent();          
    //Pulling player information from table row tag 
    var playerID = parentRow.attr("player_id");  //playerID is 'undefined' when alerted.

    refreshPlayer(playerID);
});
```

HTML

```
<tr player_id="123">
   <td><a class="add_player">Tester</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the correct element? Your code looks correct. Have you used Firebug to debug it?

Comment: I haven't turned on Firebug yet but I'm pretty sure that I'm referencing the correct element.  As an FYI to everyone, the above code is embedded immediately after the AJAX response has been loaded and not in a document.ready block.  I'm not sure if that matters or not.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have this working is this, abandoning `livequery()` for the now native `live()`:

```
$('a[class=add_player]').live('click', function(event) { 
    var playerID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('player_id');                  

    alert(playerID);

    refreshPlayer(playerID);
    return false;
});
```